# abstract class way for explicit implementation interface

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

today I was reading through the explicit implementation interface. I came to know one of it's use is to restrict clients to access the interface methods through the object of the class.

Is there any way we can create the same feature using abstract class? Like, restricting access to methods through the object of the derived class?

Comment: do you mean that you want a feature to only access the abstract class'  methods through the abstract class?

Comment: can I ask why? what scenario do you want to solve with that?

Comment: well, i was just wondering if it is possible. I do not have a scenario to do this, but I am just trying to understand if this is really a special feature with explicit implementation of interface, or we can tweak and play with abstract classes, and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a method as `protected` - then it is only available to that class and subclasses (it isn't on the `public` API). However, if you wanted to, you can't `override` it to make it `public` in a derived class - you'd need to `new` it:

```
abstract class Foo {
    protected void Bar() {...}
}
class SuperFoo : Foo {
    new public void Bar() { base.Bar(); } // <==== ugly
}
```

Comment: I want a way to only access the abstract methods through the abstract class reference variable. Not through the derived class reference variable, even though derived class can have the method implementation. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @DeepakRaj the abstract methods can be used fine as long as they are public; so if `Foo` had a `public abstract void SomeMethod();` you can do `Foo foo = new SuperFoo(); foo.SomeMethod();`

Comment: thanks Marc for the explanation. With the same example, if we have `SuperFoo sfoo = new SuperFoo();`, is there a way to restrict doing  `sfoo.SomeMethod();` **?**